# How to add two shared variables in theano?

Tags: theano

```
A=theano.shared(np.random.randn(2,3))
B=theano.shared(np.random.randn(3,4))
C=A+B
```

`print C` gives `Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0`

I want the value of C. How do I get it?

Comment: please indicate cross-posting to other places. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code as it is will not work since the shapes of your shared variables do not align.

Correcting your example, you can do

```
import theano
import numpy as np

A = theano.shared(np.random.randn(3, 4))
B = theano.shared(np.random.randn(3, 4))
C = A + B
```

Then this is correctly evaluable. If you are working in command line, then `C.eval()` will do the trick. However, the more general and comprehensive approach to this is to create a theano function.

```
f = theano.function([], C)
```

Then you can call `f()` and get the value of `C`. If your computation depended on other (non-shared) symbolic variables, you would provide the necessary values as arguments to the function (this also works with `eval` by specifying a dictionary with the relevant entries).